# Not able to import android.support.design.internal.*

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx, android-support-design, material-components-android

Trying to remove the animation on bottom navigation bar.
My Gradle is sync properly with library

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.0'
```

I tried checking the past answers to this type of question but still the
design keyword in the import statement appears in red

**This is my helper class**

```
package com.shubham.exp;

import android.util.Log;

import android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView;
import android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationItemView;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class helper {
    public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try {
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setShiftingMode(false);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
        }
    }
}
```

> error: package android.support.design.internal does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support library **29.0.0** [**doesn't exist**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions). Remove this line.

```
//implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.0'
```

You have 2 options:

- **Migrate to androidx** and use `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`
- Use support library 28.0.0 : `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'`

Finally **remove** the import of the internal packages (you don't need them).

```
//import android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView;
//import android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView;
```

Comment: thanks for the help i was able to run the project.But could not stop the animation on select

Comment: Hi @AmAteur8BP.This is a separate problem. It has nothing to do with your question. You may wish to consider asking a separate question. Also it is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

With the new `AndroidX` artifact, support libraries are no longer used. So you have to migrate it to `AndroidX`(if you didn't already done that) and in the above code, you need to remove the package import,

```
import android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView; 
import android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView;
```